Mongo Aggregation Query to Sort Nested Data
I want to sort nested array in MongoDb with c# driver. But there is not much i could do. I have a BuildFilter() method that does the filter and i had come to solution using Linq but it is lot slower while using linq. And i found out my indexing was not workable using that linq approach. I found out mongodb sort are not consistent, may be something i am missing to use as every pageload i am getting sorted order but not like first data is being always first, it changes in every page load when i was doing sort on same values. I want to use Aggregation query or proper linq query that will translate it into proper aggrgation. I want to pass BuildFilter() in match stage.Below is a demo of document structure
public class AB
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}

    .
    .
    .
    public List<BC> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class BC
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Score {get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
    public List<CD> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class CD
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

Now, i want to sort data by Amount. I am facing complexity while unwinding,sorting and regrouping it to existing structure and i am using offset pagination and i can have multiple sort at a time. that can be with amount First,then UserName.
I did something like this.
FilterDefinition<T> filter = BuildFilter(pageType);
result = await _collection.AsQueryable()
                .Where(document => filter.Inject()).Select(x => new
{
    AB = x,
    MaxScore = x.Bs.First(x => x.ID == pageType.ID)
            .Score,


})
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.MaxScore)
    .ThenBy(n => n.AB.UserName.ToLower())
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage)
    .Take(itemsPerPage)
    .Select(y => y.AB).ToListAsync();

This approach is not looking good. How can i do it in different way so that I can get data faster and
indexing will also work. A proper linq query will also be highly appreciated that will translate linq to proper aggregation query. Thank You
